# Rails generate fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rubygems

I am trying to start a project using Ruby on Rails, and I am running into a problem generating a controller.

I followed the installation guide (I have spent a day trying to get a successful installation on MacOS) and I am able to run

```
rails new my-app
```

Once I cd into my-app, I am able to

```
rails s
```

and open the default page on my localhost:3000.

EDIT: edited to reflect the correct command used

However; when I try to generate a new page

```
rails g controller home index
```

I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<main>'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/server.rb:9:in `call'
    16: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    15: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    12: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
     9: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     8: from /Users/marcoscampos/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/definition.rb:228:in `specs_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/lib/bundler/definition.rb:490:in `materialize': Could not find sqlite3-1.4.2, puma-5.4.0, bootsnap-1.7.7, byebug-11.1.3, nio4r-2.5.8, msgpack-1.4.2, bindex-0.8.1, nokogiri-1.12.3, websocket-driver-0.7.5, sassc-2.4.0, ffi-1.15.3, racc-1.5.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'


gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have tried several "solutions" but unfortunately, nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions?

Installation guides used:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server
[https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/~mirfan/files/install-rails.pdf](https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/%7Emirfan/files/install-rails.pdf)

Comment: The error is that the gems in your gemfile aren't found. Are you using something like RVM or rbenv? What happens when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @melcher I get the following success message `Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use bundle info [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.` but `rails g` command still fails. I am using rbenv

Comment: `74 gems now installed` implies the gems weren't there originally but are there now. Can you see if the `rails g` error is the same / post what it again if it's different?

Comment: `rails g` error stays the same as the original post even after running `bundle install`, and the same success message appears if I try it again

Comment: Is that `rails g home index` command you are trying? Wouldn't it be `rails g controller home index`?

Comment: you are correct, I have updated it to show the command I used which is the one that includes `controller`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there had been a misconfiguration during the installation (probably from trying different ways of installing ruby on rails) but I managed to fix the above by setting the right path for the gems installation with the following command

```
bundle config set path 'vendor/cache'
```